# UIPopoverController over UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have a main view with a button, when clicked will open a `UIPopoverController`, in a `UIPopoverController` there is another button which should open another `UIPopoverController`. Is it possible to do?

Comment: From the "iOS Human Interface Guidelines": *Ensure that only one popover is visible onscreen at a time. You shouldn’t display more than one popover (or custom view designed to look and behave like a popover) at the same time. In particular, you should avoid displaying a cascade or hierarchy of popovers simultaneously, in which one popover emerges from another.*

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple says you should not use `UIPopoverController` over `UIPopoverController`,

Instead you can use `UINavigationController` in side `UIPopoverController`.

Edit:-
rmaddy's Comment

From the "iOS Human Interface Guidelines": Ensure that only one popover is visible onscreen at a time. You shouldn’t display more than one popover (or custom view designed to look and behave like a popover) at the same time. In particular, you should avoid displaying a cascade or hierarchy of popovers simultaneously, in which one popover emerges from another